MPAndroid Line chart cannot draw from right to left?
I'm trying to draw a graph using MPAndroid line chart like the one below

My issue is that I'm able to plot the loop above the X axis, but when I start drawing backwards, It gives me java.lang.NegativeArraySizeExceptionerror.
I have to start decreasing the X-axis value entries to draw backwards and touch back the starting point of the loop. Is there any solution to this? My data is real time incoming data from sensors. I tried using two different datasets also, one for positive Y values and other for negative Yvalues, but it just doesn't take the x-axis entries in reverse order. It should be a simple line drawing between two given points, no matter what the direction is.

can anyone help me with this?

I tried doing this both with MPAndroid chart & Graphhview. However, either of them could not solve my problem so I got rid of both and went back to basics with canvas drawing using Drawline Function. I guess These libraries are good with plotting data in one direction only.
